# Unable to run multiple gradle commands on same projects

Tags: gradle

I have a situation where i need to run multiple gradle tasks, in parallel.

For example: I am using gretty(org.akhikhl.gretty:gretty:+) plugin for running embedded webserivce, which runs my service.

So I ran, `gradle jettyStart`.

Now I have some scripts that need to be ran while the webservice is running, means the `gradle jettyRun` has run.

I have a migration script written in groovy, which I can call using `gradle runScript <script_name>`

but since this scripts calls the webservice apis, i need the service to be up. But the case is, once i keep running `gradle jettyRun`, i cant run `gradle runScript` until unless i stop the other tasks.

How can I resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `start` (e.g. appStart) family of gretty tasks which starts jetty in background and exits. Then you can use any other gradle task on this project. To stop jetty you can use `stop`-tasks

You can get list of available tasks from documentation:
http://akhikhl.github.io/gretty-doc/Gretty-tasks.html

Comment: This functionality is broken for me right now. See https://github.com/akhikhl/gretty/issues/400 - Anyone, Please Vote up this issue if you need it fixed!